# WebSocket closes on send

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket

So I saw this great blog post, [Experimenting with Node.js](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/experimenting-with-node-js/). I decided to try and set it up on my own using the author's [gist](https://gist.github.com/488562/90dfad4fc3bf52c136ecb5149c5bace53107c31d). It didn't work.

Further debugging shows me that the the websocket is connecting fine, but is closing as soon as 'send' is invoked. Here is the wireshark trace(forgive the weird spacing):

```
GET /test HTTP/1.1

Host: 127.0.0.1:8000

Sec-WebSocket-Key2: 3   j 92 9   62" 7 0 8 8

Upgrade: WebSocket

Connection: Upgrade

Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000

Sec-WebSocket-Key1: 96'5% S72.93?06



......(bHTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake

Upgrade: WebSocket

Connection: Upgrade

Sec-WebSocket-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:3000

Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://127.0.0.1:8000/test



.4.R....mh.....{.{"action":"move","x":450,"y":22,"w":1146,"h":551}.
```

I've tried this in both Chrome and Firefox 4.0 beta. They both exhibit the same behavior. If I go to the [original blog site](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/experimenting-with-node-js/), it works fine.

Another thing. If I go into the JS console in either FF or Chrome and I do the following:

```
ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/test')
ws.send("foo")
```

It immediately disconnects and does not send the message. The server shows the connection and handshake, but never receives a message.

I've found a few questions here that were similar but were either resolved without posting the fix or did not seem to apply in this situation. I can post the code from the [gist](https://gist.github.com/488562/90dfad4fc3bf52c136ecb5149c5bace53107c31d) if it will make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major headslap. Despite believing I had the latest version of Node.js installed I did not. I have a couple machines with Node.js on them I must have lost track. I had Node.js v0.1.96. After upgrading to v0.1.102, everything is working fine.

Sorry guys! :-D

Answer (score 3):

The CloseEvent has a "code" property that will give you information about why your connection was closed.

> "Returns an unsigned short containing the close code send by the server. The following values are permitted status codes."

A variety of code values are supported.  Here are the most prominent:

- 1000: CLOSE_NORMAL
- 1001:     CLOSE_GOING_AWAY
- 1002: CLOSE_PROTOCOL_ERROR
- 1003: CLOSE_UNSUPPORTED
- 1005: CLOSE_NO_STATUS

[See CloseEvent API docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CloseEvent) for more.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12231080)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I will have it in mind next time!

Answer (score 1):

In Android, for me the problem is on how I am handling the data.  I was able to pinpoint by doing the following.

1. Check if something is wrong in NodeJs (Server) - By commenting the send item `ws.send(JSON.stringify(whatever));`.
2. Check if something is wrong in Android (Client) - By commenting the onMessage. `Log.d("TAG","onMessage: " +text);` Then just see how you are handling the data and comment out those parts.  Run the log cats on `onClosed, onFailure`

This should help you in pinpointing the problem at least, because NodeJs Websocket help is hard to find.  `Languages are not hard - its the documentation, support and lack of community which is difficult.` Good cook books, project video tutorials are hard to come by.

I was getting the data as Json arrays and trying to populate in recycler view the wrong way.  This was the problem for me.

You should also try the following code in your node.js file to see the reason

```
// Connection Closed
ws.on('close', function close(code, reason) {
console.log('ws is closed with code: ' + code + ' reason: ' + reason);
});

// On Error
ws.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("error occured" +e);
});
```

For full problem and solution please see here : [Websocket closed code: 1006 Node Android okhttp3 AmazonEc2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910849/websocket-closed-code-1006-node-android-okhttp3-amazonec2/61925485#61925485)

Answer (score 0):

For the problem of disconnect happening when you issue the send from the browser, you need to wait for the onopen event to fire before issuing a send:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/test');
conn.onopen = function (e) {
    conn.send('foo');
}
conn.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log('got: ' + e.data);
}
```