# Websocket closed code: 1006 Node Android okhttp3 AmazonEc2

Tags: android, node.js, amazon-web-services, websocket, okhttp

I am having an issue with Websocket `ws is closed with code: 1006 reason:`

**Environment**

```
Amazon EC2 Instance  : t2.micro Ubuntu 18.04
Node : v12.16.3
Websocket : https://github.com/websockets/ws : 7.3.0
MongoDb : shell version v4.2.6
MongoDriver : NodeJs 3.5.7
Okhhtp3 : implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.6.0'
```

I am getting data from Websockets -> MongoDb and trying to populate into recycler view.  The data comes fine if I do log.d but when I populate into the recycler view - it does fine on app launch, and one more time when coming to activity but after that I start getting 1006 error.

**NodeJs (Server)**

```
// Websocket variables
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8000 });
console.log('Websocket active on port 8000...');

// Connect To Mongo
MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true, authSource: 'admin' }, function (err, client) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    const db = client.db(dbName);

    // New Connection
    wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

        // Message Received
        ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {

            // Json Parse String To Access Child Elements
            var iJson = JSON.parse(message);
            const c = db.collection('chats');
            c.find({ "owner": iJson.owner_id }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(docs));
            });
        });

        // Connection Closed
        ws.on('close', function close(code, reason) {
            console.log('ws is closed with code: ' + code + ' reason: ' + reason);
        });
    });
});
```

**Android (Client)**

```
private WebSocket webSocket;

// Initiate The Socket Connection
private void initiateSocketConnection() {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(WebSocketClient.SERVER_PATH).build();
    webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, new SocketListener());

}

// Private WebSocketListener Class
private class SocketListener extends WebSocketListener {

    public SocketListener() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosed(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket,
        int code,
        @NotNull String reason) {
        super.onClosed(webSocket,
            code,
            reason);

        Log.d("TAG",
            "onClosed: " + code + "-" + reason);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket,
        @NotNull Throwable t,
        okhttp3.@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Response response) {
        super.onFailure(webSocket,
            t,
            response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket,
        @NotNull String text) {
        super.onMessage(webSocket,
            text);

        String chat = "{\"chat\":" + text + "}";

        Log.d("TAG",
            "onMessage: " + chat);

        lIndividualChatList.clear();

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(chat.trim());

            // Check If User Array Has Anything
            JSONArray returnArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("chat");

            for (int l = 0; l < returnArray.length(); l++) {
                if (returnArray.length() > 0) {

                    // Get The Json Object
                    JSONObject returnJSONObject = returnArray.getJSONObject(l);

                    // Get Details
                    String owner = returnJSONObject.optString("owner");
                    lIndividualChatList.add(new IndividualListModel(owner));
                }
            }

            // Use The Adapter To Populate The Recycler View
            aIndividualChatList = new IndividualListAdapter(lIndividualChatList);
            rvList.setAdapter(aIndividualChatList);

            aIndividualChatList.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket,
        okhttp3.@NotNull Response response) {
        super.onOpen(webSocket,
            response);
    }
}
```

Comment: To help troubleshoot this set up a `ws.on('error',...)` event handler. Do you get anything interesting?

Comment: ws.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log("error occured" +e);
        }); not firing

Comment: @O.Jones solved thanks for pointing out in logging more errors, I logged as many on server and client side... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wierd part is that it was working once or twice before failing which was causing confusion.  If it always failed and fave a logcat that would have been nice.  The best way is to log all the possible errors/failures on server and client and see the message.

**First Put The Log Inside On Failure**

```
@Override
public void onFailure(@NotNull WebSocket webSocket, @NotNull Throwable t, okhttp3.@org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Response response) {
    super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response);

    Log.d("TAG", "websocket failure: " + t + response);
}
```

**That gave the following message :**

```
: `websocket failure: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: 
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.null`
```

**Then Wrap the popluation of recycler view in this**

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {

  // Poplulate the recycler view here....

}
```